# Aborting Jenkins Build from Command Line?

Tags: jenkins

I want to stop a Jenkins build that is happening on my localhost using the terminal.

I used curl to stop the build, but it asks for a password.

Is there another way of stopping a Jenkins build securely?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop Jenkins jobs using cURL and the [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). You will need the credentials (user name and access token) to use the API. You'd provide the credentials like so:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/BUILD_ID/stop \
  --user USER:TOKEN
```

If you can't use the Jenkins API (you don't have credentials) your only option is to shut down the Jenkins slave running on your computer. This should cause any running job to fail. How you shut down the slave depends on what type of slave is running on your machine (SSH, web start, etc).